# Inference from conditional observations

Tags: normal-distribution, inference

Let $(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ be an i.i.d. random sampling from a conditional normal distribution ${\cal N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ distribution given some event $A$ possibly parameter-dependent: for instance when we sample ${\cal N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ but we only retain $x_i$ when $x_i \in [\mu-3\sigma, \mu+3\sigma]$. Are there some known methods to perform statistcal inference on the parameters?

Comment: Do you know what the conditioning event is *a priori* (up to the values of the parameters)?

Comment: Yes, as if you set $\mu$ and $\sigma$ in a computer and you simulate but you reject values outside $A=[\mu-3\sigma, \mu+3\sigma]$.

Answer (score 1):

If you throw out observations outside 3 sigma from the mean the distribution you end up with is a truncated normal.  You just divide the normal density by the norming constant that makes the integral over the restricted region equal 1.  Then you can write down the likelihood function for your data and compute the maximum likelihood estimate.  I am addressing you specific example and not the generalconditional distribution question.

Comment: Yes, of course maximum likelihood ia available, but what about a confidence interval about $\mu$ ?

Comment: If the maximum likelihood estimator is well behaved then you could use its asymptotic normal distribution to construct approximate confidence intervals.  I think bootstrap confidence intervals would work in this case also.

Comment: Asymptotic normal distribution is not "standard" when the support is parameter-dependent, is it ?

Comment: @stephane I think you are right.  The endpoints for the distribution are functions of mu and sigma in your case so this is not a regular case for the mle.  I don't know what would happen with bootstrap confidence intervals in this case. It seems that there is information about mu in the center of the distrbution and in the extremes.  What about just using the sample mean to estimate mu.  This would ignore some information in the data but couldn't we construct approximate confidence limits based on the CLT?  Maybe we could show that bootstrap confidence intervals for the sample mean would work.

Comment: @stephaneLaurent Did you want to estimate sigma as well?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent This problem strikes me as being interesting in many ways. What is the best estimate for the mean and standard deviation and how do you construct best confidence intervals. Are the mles good estimates? Do bootstrap confidence intervals work in this case? I see that [X$_($$_n$$_)$ - X$_b$]/3 is a consistent estimate for sigma where X$_b$ denotes the sample mean. Also [X$_b$-X$_($$_1$$_)$]/3 is consistent for sigma and the average of the two is unbiased based on symmetry considerations.

Comment: In addition to X$_b$ being an unbiased estimator for mu, I think [X$_($$_n$$_)$+X$_($$_1$$_)$]/2 is also unbiased for mu. Combining some of these estimates by averaging them might give better ones. I don't know if this problem has been studied much. Is there any literature on it? I think the answers to the bootstrap question on confidence intervals might be new.